# Transforming Map using map in scala

Tags: scala

Given a string I want to create a map that for each character in a string will give the number of times the character occurs in a string. The following function makes a map from character to a list of Strings.

```
def wordOccurrences(w: String) = {
  val lower = w.toLowerCase.toList
  lower.groupBy(t => t)
}
```

Now I wanted to alter the last line to:

```
lower.groupBy(t => t) map ( (x,y) => x -> y.length)
```

But it doesn't work, can someone explain why and how to fix it?

Comment: A note unrelated to the answer: `t => t` is the `identity` function which is already defined in the `Prelude` and that you can use as follows: `lower.groupBy(identity)`.

Comment: Also, it's probably just a typo and I already fixed it, but the arrow to define lambdas in scala is `=>`, not `->`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `map`ping purposes, a `Map[K, V]` is an `Iterable[(K, V)]` (notice the extra pair of parentheses, identifying a tuple type), meaning that when you `map` over it you have pass a function that goes from `(K, V)` to your target type.

What you are doing, however, is passing a function that takes *two independent* arguments, rather then a *single tuple* argument.

The difference can be seen by inspecting the types of these two functions in the Scala shell:

```
scala> :t (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
(Int, Int) => Int

scala> :t (p: (Int, Int)) => p._1 + p._2
((Int, Int)) => Int
```

Notice how the former takes two arguments while the latter takes a single tuple.

What you can do is pass a function which decomposes the tuple so that you can bind the components of the tuple independently:

```
lower.groupBy(t => t) map { case (x, y) => x -> y.length }
```

or alternatively pass a function which uses the tuple without deconstructing it

```
lower.groupBy(t => t) map (p => p._1 -> p._2.length)
```

#### Note

Dotty, which is the current project Scala's original author Martin Odersky is working on and that will probably become Scala 3, supports the syntax you are proposing, calling the feature *function arity adaptation*. This has been discussed, along with other feature, in Odersky's 2016 Keynote at Scala eXchange, "From DOT to Dotty" ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iobC5yGRWoo) the video taped at 2017 Voxxed Days CERN).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 lower.groupBy(t => t).mapValues(_.length)
```

Comment: I know that but I would like see how can I achieve the same thing using map.